# specific treatments through conditions with xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I wanna extract an xpath field and manipulate it depending on what is contained in the field, in this case i want my xpath to detect whether or not the field contains a word and if it does to do X treatment otherwise to do an Y treatement and then insert it in my scrapy item

I will try and explain it in a pseudo code alongside my actual xpath code

i tried using .extract(), manipulating the field as a string and then inserting it in my item, had a lot of different problems and it was such a mess

```
#my current code
new.add_xpath('source',"substring-before(.//h3/a/@href,'?')")
#what i wanna achieve
new.add_xpath('source',if .//h3/a/@href contains "profile.php" :
                          substring-before(.//h3/a/@href,'id')
                       else :
                          substring-before(.//h3/a/@href,'?'))
```

id expect the extracted field to be either ./XXX.XXX.?.XXX if it has profile.php in it or ./XXX.XXX if it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume your are ussing XPath 1.0 because of python. Then, you can output directly the string you want with this expression:

```
substring-before(
   .//h3/a/@href, 
   concat(
      substring(
         'id',
         1 div contains(.//h3/a/@href, 'profile.php')
      ), 
      substring(
         '?',
         1 div not(contains(.//h3/a/@href, 'profile.php'))
      )
   )
)
```

Test in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/cca4e5a85df20137b923d0b6f06bf6cc

**Do note**: like in C, boolean values are cast to numbers 0 (`false()`) and 1 (`true()`), then you might use the extended reals representation (`NaN`, `Inf`, `-Inf`) as argument for the `substring()` function [like the examples given by the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-substring)